# JQuery Ajax to PHP update div during query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress

I'm importing 4000 rows from a CSV file. Page 1 shows CSV file on server with PROCESS button.
`Onclick` button, I use **JQuery Ajax** to call the necessary **PHP code** that does the import. After doing the relevant checks, updating records and inserting records etc, the whole import process takes approx 30 seconds to 1 min.

What I'm trying to do is display progress of this import while its processing the php code.
ie:

```
Total records to import: 4000
Total users imported: 20 [div id=usersImported - this number dynamically increments while importing]
Total users updated: 30 [div id=usersUpdated - same here re incrementing]
Etc..
```

I'm not sure what the correct question is, because I've tried updating the `DIVs (usersImported and usersUpdated)` from the php code - couldn't get this to work. This just returns my script code to the browser but doesnt actually execute it

I've also tried doing an echo in the php after its either updated or inserted.. ie: usersImported1 then usersImported2 then usersImported3.. then in my JQuery success I'm trying:

`if( txt.match( "usersImported" ).length > 0 ) { ..` with update div innerHTML code with leading number..

This doesn't work because the php is not flushing as it processes, even though I've tried `ob_flush();` and `flush();` Or is it because the success only runs in ajax once the whole php code is complete? Is there a JQuery while: command?

So the real question I guess, is: what is the correct way to do this? From PHP update the DIVs or from $ajax update div based on PHP echos? This is similar to a progress bar update, except I want to update certain div's based on what happens during process time.

I would appreciate a basic example or a link to a working sample.

Comment: it's like ajax upload with live information

Answer (score 0):

Guess the ajax doesn't fire since you don't close the http, it sits and wait for more to come.

You need streams or chunk up your work at server.

A dirty fix would be to let the updater write percentage to a static public file, read by the client and just keep polling that file. (add an randomized querystring so you get pass caches).

Comment: a similar case but in asp section [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2792558/are-there-progress-update-events-in-jquery-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

There is not any direct method. You can write your PHP process status to any external source like `file` or `database` and on the client side read that status after a specific time.

Hope this article will give you a direction:

- [Progress bar for a lengthy PHP process](http://spidgorny.blogspot.it/2012/02/progress-bar-for-lengthy-php-process.html)

Comment: For this to work, I would need to pass the function the value of $size.. and that I would do during my PHP process.. updating a field in the DB called "importProgress" with the number of rows out of 4000 completed... correct? hmmmmmm

Comment: @Mark: Yes, something like this.